# Android: Is it possible to have a scrollview in a flipper in a tabview?

Tags: android, vertical-scrolling

I have a **TabView** and on its first tab I have a **ViewFlipper** displaying **two pages of ImageButtons** (say *buttonsPage1* and *buttonsPage2*).

When in landscape orientation, I need the image buttons pages to be scrollable, so I tried to add a **ScrollView** on *buttonsPage1* and another on *buttonsPage2*. I get a StackOverflowError.

I tried then to suppress the ScrollView from the pageButtons1 and 2 and to include the ViewFlipper in a ScrollView. I got the same StackOverflowError.

If I completely remove the ViewFlipper, the applications runs as expected, no error occurs, only I **DO** need the scrolling when in landscape orientation.

Can anybody, please, give me hand to solve this issue?

Comment: posting the stack trace of the error and the snippet of code where you instantiate and use the ScrollView could be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get a StackOverflowError.

If your stack trace lists a whole bunch of internal Android methods that seem to be related to drawing your UI, then your UI is too complicated. Use [`hierarchyviewer`](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html) and your emulator to view the `View`/`ViewGroup` tree for your activity, and find ways to remove layers. For example, if your `TabWidget` does not hold a `ViewFlipper`, but rather you use an `Intent` to designate an activity that goes in the tab, that adds several layers to your `View` hierarchy more than just using `Views` as the contents of tabs.

My general rule of thumb is to try to keep my view hierarchies to single digit depth, as measured from the root through the longest branch. By the time you get to 15 layers, you are almost assuredly going to crash somewhere.

If your `StackOverflow` error does not seem to be related to drawing your UI, though, you need to post the stack trace as an edit to this question.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed a matter of complexity. HierachyViewer is priceless.